# Generate PDF from HTML with radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Currently jspdf method shows only content and images, but how to include radio button icons as well.

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
     <input type="radio">CT Scan
  
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

I want to include radio and check box icons in pdf.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f9tsu21k/1833/)

Comment: Replace checkboxes/radio buttons with images...

Answer (score 4):

Well, erm, if this list can be trusted it's not supported, as the list of supported HTML features doesn't include any input elements, at all.

[Documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML)

```
>
```

[All Supported HTML features](https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/html2pdf/showcase_supported_html.html)

Comment: is it doable or no?

Comment: Only if you convert the page or element to an image before sending it to jsPDF.